# how to get same monitor when calling wait() ,notify() or notifyAll()?

Tags: java, multithreading

main thread creating two thread t1 and t2 run() method of these thread creating two new thread c1 and c2.I want a scenario such that until c1&c2(of t1) are alive t2 will not start executing. In my code notify and wait are causing Runtime Exception.Since they are not in synchronised block, how to do this?

```
public class childTcreat2newthread {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread mainT = Thread.currentThread();
        Target ra = new Target("a");
        Thread t1 = new Thread(ra);
        t1.start();
        t1.join();

        while (ra.getC1().isAlive() == true || ra.getC2().isAlive() == true) {
            synchronized (mainT) {
                mainT.wait();
            }
        }
        new Thread(new Target("b")).start();
    }
}

class Target implements Runnable {
    Thread c1 = new Thread(new Target1("1"));

    Thread c2 = new Thread(new Target1("2"));
    String msg;

    Target(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                if (i % 10000 == 0 && j % 10000 == 0) {
                    System.out.print(msg);
                }
            }
        }

        t1.start();

        t2.start();
    }

    public Thread getC1() {
        return c1;
    }

    public Thread getC2() {
        return c2;
    }
}

class Target1 implements Runnable {

    String msg;

    Target1(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                if (i % 100000 == 0 && j % 10000 == 0) {
                    System.out.print(msg);
                }
            }
        }
        try {

            notifyAll();
            System.out.println("K");
        } catch (IllegalMonitorStateException e) {
            System.out.println("\nIllegalMonitorStateException!! in " + msg + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

wait( ) tells the calling thread to give up the monitor and go to sleep until some other thread enters the same monitor and calls notify( ).**Unable to get same monitor when calling notify**.How to do this? and **what does its importance?**

Comment: invoke `wait()` and `notify()` on an object shared between the threads.

Comment: Use `CountDownLatch` with initial value of 2. Then at the beginning of `t2.run()` call `await()` . At the end of `c1.run()` and `c2.run()` call `countDown()`. This is the way to go.. `await()` ensures a *happens-beofre* so no memory inconsistencies will be seen

Comment: thanks @TheLostMind consider the above condition-suppose if we have to apply synchronzed lock in this then which object should we prefer in this.

Comment: @dubey-theHarcourtians - You could just call `join()` for both c1 and c2 at the beginning of your `t2` thread's `run()`. If you really need a lock, then any *new / different* object is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid wait()/notify() and wherever possible use the higher-level abstractions Java provides, see: [Java Concurrency Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/highlevel.html).

Using wait()/notify(), you must use the same monitor for both calls, see [Guarded Blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html). Even if this is only for learning, I don't see a good way of making this work with wait(). You should either stick to join() or use one of the higher-level abstractions.

Answer (score 1):

As i don't have enough reputation to comment, commenting via answer

You are not locking and notifying on same object.

you are locking on `mainT` but notifying on `Target1` instance, you need to pass the locking object to `c1` and `c2`.

however i suggest you to use [java concurrent API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html)  to solve such problems

Comment: Looks kind of like an answer to me.

Answer (score 0):

What about :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread mainT = Thread.currentThread();
    Target ra = new Target("a");
    Thread t1 = new Thread(ra);
    t1.start();
    t1.getC1().join();
    t1.getC2().join()

    new Thread(new Target("b")).start();
}
```

See : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29

Comment: actually I want to use wait() & notify() not a join() on the separate instance of each c1 & c2.